# When a heading is DONE, I don't see the link

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

[image: TODO_NEXT heading with link]

[image: DONE heading with link]

I am using:

- Spacemacs: 0.200.13
- Org: 9.4

I have set org-fontify-done-headline to nil (Original value was t), to no avail.

Desired result:
Link is displayed as it is in TODO_NEXT state.

Comment: To be clear: there is a link like this [[...][Bottom-up meta-modelling...]] in the headline, it works in both cases, it is fontified as a link in the first case, but is not fontified as a link in the second case. IOW, it's a matter of appearance only, not functionality - correct?

Comment: @NickD Yes, it is a matter of appearance only, doing C-c C-o follows the link in both cases correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [a recent thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2020-09/msg01132.html) in the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html), Kyle Meyer had this to say:

> In v9.4, the default of org-fontify-done-headline changed to t, which
> results in the org-headline-done face applied.  You can set it to nil to
> restore the previous behavior.

So you might try

```el
(setq org-fontify-done-headline nil)
```

in your .emacs and see if that works for you.